# Hibernate Mapping with table constraint

Tags: java, hibernate

What is the effect or problem if I am not creating any constraint during the table creation. But I am using the constraints mapping in hibernate.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).